# Remote MS SQL or MySQL Database on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I currently have a website that uses MS SQL and I am interested in creating an iOS client for that website. I would the app to connect to a remote SQL database that is hosted on my website and then I could pull information from that database and display it locally on the device. I would like to also publish information to the database. I am open to use MySQL.

Is this possible and if so does anyone know of any good tutorials that I could check out?

Comment: You don't want to directly expose a database server to the net. Even if mysql/mssql drivers were available for ios, you don't want to do this. Instead, set up a simple webservice to be an intermediate between your device and the DBMS. The phone talks to the server via HTTP, and the service talks to the DBMS using whatever its native protocol is.

Answer (score 6):

I'd highly recommend placing a thin web layer between your database and your iOS client. You don't want iOS apps connecting directly to your database (unless this is for your own personal use for limited to a handful of people you really trust).

You could write the web layer in PHP (or whatever you fancy). At that point you can use HTTP and JSON between your iOS app and your database.

Answer (score 1):

Put a web service between the phone and the DB.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options :

- You can develop webservices/scripts or whatever server side solution that will make your database talk "publicly"
- Use a third-party library ([like this](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/09/17/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx/)) that will make your app communicate with the MySQL database.